# Serializing using Json, UWP & Unity?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, uwp, nuget, hololens

I'm developing for the HoloLens & i'm looking for best practices for serializing using Json, UWP & Unity.

Json using NuGet isn't compatible with Unity.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: make a test project; add json.net to that project; find the dll with the file explorer. Put the dll in your asset folder in unity. you will now be able to use json.net in your unity project

Comment: You should definitely check a built-in json parser https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html